# some questions about search order of GCC linker

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have some questions about gcc link order. GCC man says linker search symbols from left to right without repeatly search by default. Here is my test:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        printf("HELLO WROLD\n");
        return 0;
}
```

printf.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
        write(1, "AAA\n", 4);
}

[root@lenovo testcode]# gcc -c -fno-builtin-printf *.c
[root@lenovo testcode]# gcc -o test main.o printf.o
[root@lenovo testcode]# ./test 
AAA
[root@lenovo testcode]# gcc -o test printf.o main.o
[root@lenovo testcode]# ./test
AAA


[root@lenovo testcode]# ar rcs libprintf.a printf.o
[root@lenovo testcode]# gcc -o test libprintf.a main.o
[root@lenovo testcode]# ./test 
HELLO WROLD
[root@lenovo testcode]# gcc -o test main.o libprintf.a 
[root@lenovo testcode]# ./test 
AAA


[root@lenovo testcode]# gcc -shared -o libprintf.so printf.o 
[root@lenovo testcode]# gcc -o test libprintf.so  main.o 
[root@lenovo testcode]# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
[root@lenovo testcode]# ./test 
AAA
[root@lenovo testcode]# gcc -o test main.o libprintf.so 
[root@lenovo testcode]# ./test 
AAA
```

From the result, we can see the order of .o and .o, .o and .so make no difference, only order of .o and .a has the effect. But that is inconsistant with gcc man page. So why?

Comment: I have used -v, but still i don't understand why. Can you explain this in detail?

Comment: I can't use -nodefaultlibs, for some functions in crt like _start should be exist.

Comment: I guess I TL;DR-ed before. In what way do you think 'it' is inconsistent with the gcc amn page?

Comment: the order of .o and .o, .o and .so should be matter, which means it should get same result as .o and .a. It's not, as you see from my result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gcc does indeed process the object files from left to right.  When you have

```
gcc -o test libprintf.a main.o
```

The first object file gcc sees is `libprintf.a`. There are no unresolved symbols for the output object at this point, so nothing from `libprintf.a` is used/needed.  Next, `main.o` is processed, the linker makes a note of the fact that `printf` is unresolved, and then proceeds to process the implicit libraries where it is able to resolve the `printf` symbol that was unresolved `in main.o`.

Likewise, when you have:

```
gcc -o test main.o libprintf.a
```

The first object file to be processed is `main.o`, where the unresolved symbol `printf` is noted, the next to be processed is `libprintf.a` from which the linker is able to resolve `printf`.  When `libc` is eventually processed, `printf` is already resolved so the instance of `printf` in `libc` is not used.

When linking with .o files:

```
gcc -o test main.o printf.o
```

The `libc` library is again treated as if it was specified at the end of the command line, so the `printf` symbol is resolved from the first (left-to-right) object file that defines it.

For both of the `libprintf.so` cases, the `libc` library is again treated as if it was specified at the end of the command line. What is different from the static library case is that the left-to-right ordering of the `*.so` libraries determines the run-time dynamic symbol search order.  Since this order has `libprintf.so` before the implicit `libc.so`, the version of `printf` in `libprintf.so` is used.

```
gcc -o test libprintf.so  main.o
gcc -o test main.o libprintf.so
```

As an additional experiment, you could try:

```
gcc -o test main.o -lc libprintf.so
```

This should show the version of `printf` being used from `libc.so` instead of `libprintf.so` because `-lc` comes before `libprintf.so` in left-to-right order.

Comment: Edited to add explanations for these cases... sorry for neglecting those in the initial response.