# How is it possible to link static libraries with the same symbol?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, linkage

I have two static libraries foo.a and bar.a. Each library contains the same symbol:

```sh
$ nm foo.a | grep _some_symbol
                 U _some_symbol
0000000000000000 R _some_symbol

$ nm bar.a | grep _some_symbol
                 U _some_symbol
0000000000000020 R _some_symbol
```

When I try to link them using `g++ /*other_static_libs*/ foo.a bar.a`, it's OK, but I do not understand why multiple definition error is missing during linking.

Do you have any thoughts on when this might be possible?

Comment: That's not possible.  Unlike .o files, when searching .a files for an identifier, the linker is happy with the first one it encounters that has the identifier.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585225/some-questions-about-search-order-of-gcc-linker

Comment: The second symbol is simply ignored

Comment: Put each library into it's own namespace and recompile.  Multiple definitions breaks the One-Definition-Rule with no diagnostic required and is Undefined Behaviour, see also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Comment: [Put each library into it's own namespace and recompile.]
It is impossible, foo and bar includes different version of the same 3rd party library with given symbol. BTW, I know how to solve this issue.

Comment: [with no diagnostic required]


It makes sense. But sometimes the linker fails with 'multiple definition' error, sometimes it doesn't. It looks strange, especially since it is easy to determine that there is more than one definition during linking.

Comment: @eaniconer different linkers have different rules and then there is the problem of the order in which fixups are done (and modules included) which also differs between linkers.  So the Standard just says _"no diagnostic required"_.  If a linker can spot the problem and if it is a problem on that platform then the linker is free to report it.  The global namespace is a problem which all library writers should try to avoid.